# Why does my python HttpServer dump all received requests on close?

Tags: python, http, server, httpserver

I have the following request handler:

```py
class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self) -> None:
        if self.path == "/myRoute":
            self.handle_route()

    def handle_route(self):
        print("Handling /myRoute")
        received_bytes = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length']))
        data = json.loads(received_bytes.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"'))
        logger.info(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("{\"Success\":true,\"Exception\":\"\"}", "utf-8"))
```

I am successfully handling `POST`s to the route `/myRoute`. However, when I close after the following usage:

```py
my_server = server.HTTPServer(("localhost", 8080), MyHandler)
my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_server.serve_forever)
my_thread.daemon = True
my_thread.start()
# do some work
my_server.server_close()
```

I see a "dump" of all the `POST`s received. This makes me think I am not properly flushing my response(s) back to the client:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Aug/2020 12:01:58] "POST /myRoute HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Aug/2020 12:02:35] "POST /myRoute HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Aug/2020 12:03:11] "POST /myRoute HTTP/1.1" 200 -
.
.
.
```

What makes me think this *even more* is that it is the same number of requests I received during the execution of my application.

Am I properly sending my responses back to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I simply overrided the `BaseHttpRequestHandler.log_message()` to do nothing:

```
    def log_message(self, format: str, *args: Any) -> None:
        """
        Override of BaseHTTPRequestHandler to skip logging of messages.
        Parameters
        ----------
        format: str
            The str format.
        args: Any
            The values to log.
        """
```

Then I only logged what I was interested in via the typical `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` in my route handling methods.